# How connect OBS with VPS which has ffmpeg for live streaming?

Tags: apache, ffmpeg, centos, streaming

Helo I've a VPS on Centos 7 with Apache and ffmpeg. 
How can I do live streaming on this server using OBS on my local PC to encode and publish to this server and after embed this live video in my wordpress website to allow every device to watch the live video?
Thank you all

Comment: Nginx rtmp ....

Answer (score 0):

OBS is using RTMP protocol. You would need a server that can serve RTMP, Nginx web server has a plugin that let's you do that. There is no need to use Apache or FFMPEG, Nginx would be alot easier.